# Removing formatting (\t\r) from a Stream Reader

Tags: c#, .net, sql

I'm importing an .sql file that I created with SQLExplorer into my .NET program using StreamReader (which will eventually be passed through OdbcConnection, fyi.)  The problem is that when I use the `ReadToEnd()` method it not only imports the SQL itself, but it imports all of the formatting.  So the string is littered with `\r` and `\t` and the like.

I've been looking at both using split or possibly regex to break the string down and remove the unwanted bits and pieces.  But before throwing a bunch of effort into that I wondered if there was perhaps something I'm missing in the StreamReader class?  Is there a way to tell it to just ignore the formatting characters?

Here's the code I have right now:

```
public static Object SQLQueryFileCall(String SQLQueryFileName){

        string SQLQuery = "";
        string directory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName( System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
        SQLQueryFileName = directory + "\\" + SQLQueryFileName;

        //read in the file and pass to ODBC, return a Object[] of whatever comes back...
        try{
            using (StreamReader myStreamReader = new StreamReader(SQLQueryFileName)) {

                SQLQuery = myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
                Console.WriteLine(SQLQuery);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            //Find the error
            Console.WriteLine("File could not be read:");
            string error = e.Message;
            MessageBox.Show(error);
            return null;
        }
}
```

Feel free to offer any advice you might have on the code, seeing as I'm pretty new.

But yeah, mostly I'm just hoping there's a method in the StreamReader class that I'm just not understanding.  I've gone to Microsoft's online documentation, and I feel I've given it a good look, but then again, I'm new and perhaps the concept skipped over my head?

Any help?

NOTE:  There are multiple `\t` that are in the middle of some of the lines, and they do need to be removed.  Hence using trim would...be tricky at least.

Comment: Why do you even need to get rid of the formatting? Can't you use it as-is?

Comment: Well right now I get something along the lines of `SELECT \t* \rFROM \tMyTable` etc etc.  When I toss that into OdbcConnection and it gets thrown over to DB for i...well, it doesn't like them.  It would much prefer a blank space.

Comment: @AdamMaras - and you were right, it was in fact an id10t error.  I forgot I had inserted a line into the code that hadn't worked that, in fact, gave me the exact same error in my SQL Editor.  So I removed the line and it took my string, formatting and all...  Part of me wants to delete this question now, but the question is still legitimate even if it wasn't the problem.  So I'll just leave it up...

Comment: I'll go ahead and add an answer along these lines, just to steer others in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL, by definition, shouldn't have a problem with whitespaces like tabs and newlines throughout code. Verify that your actual SQL is correct first.

Also, blindly stripping whitespace could potentially have an impact on textual data contained within your script; what happens if you have a string literal that contains a tab character?

Comment: Yup, this is the literal answer to my actual problem (rather than my imagined one).  The problem was with my SQL, I just misinterpreted the error message I got.  But, as mentioned before, I'll leave this question up for anyone who really needs to try and remove `\t` mid line for whatever reason.

Answer (score 2):

Well, `myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();` will get you everything. The easiest way to get rid of most unneeded whitespace is to read it line-by-line and then simply `.Trim()` every line.

```
 using (StreamReader myStreamReader = new StreamReader(SQLQueryFileName)) 
 {
    string line;
    List<string> lines = new List<string();

    while ((line = myStreamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
        lines.Add(line.Trim());

    SQLQuery = string.Join("\n", lines);
    Console.WriteLine(SQLQuery);
 }
```

Comment: Line by line and trim is not going to remove embedded \t

Comment: @Blam - correct but most `\t` will be at the start of the lines. Any `\t` further along you maybe don't want to remove.

Comment: Since it's SQL it's perfectly fine if there are no `\t` in it, they just come with the .sql (which is being done by someone else who uses tabs to make things more readable.)  So, there are embedded `\t` all over the place that do need to be removed.  This would be an excellent solution otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

```
SQLQuery = Regex.Replace(SQLQuery, @"\t|\n|\r", "");
```

Better to use as you could remove content of SQL insertions:

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileName)) 
{
   String line;
   List<string> lines = new List<string();

   while ((line = myStreamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
       SQLQuery += line.Trim() + "\n";
}
```

Comment: I am not the downvoter, but the OP *explicitly* said not to like regex'ing the string in the first place.

Comment: Right, that's a terrible idea... what happens when two different identifiers/keywords are separated only by a newline or a tab? This will remove the necessary whitespace between them.

Comment: To be fair to Zarathos, this just might be his polite way of telling me that Regex really isn't all that hard and perhaps I should just cowboy-up and do it that way ;-).  Looking at that line of code, Regex seems far less intimidating than when I first started reading about it.

Comment: Wouldn't your line work if it it said `(SQLQuery, @"\t|\n|\r", " ")` so that the `\t` are replaced with spaces?  A white space can universally take the place of a tab in SQL, since a tab is generally just 4 white spaces anyway...  I would think..

Comment: Correct, but let's say you are reading INSERT INTO directives from that SQL and the text into them is keeping tabs formatted like \t... you would remove them from your database and, by consequent, from your output.

Comment: Yes that's the real problem behind my solution. Preserve your data as best as you can.

Answer (score 0):

```
 using (StreamReader myStreamReader = new StreamReader(SQLQueryFileName)) 
 {  
    while ((line = myStreamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(line.Trim().Replace(@"\t"," ")
    }
 }
```

If it is a display and not content issue I think you could use WPF and a RichTextBox.

Comment: Could I use that same thing, but with `myStreamReader.ReadAllLines()' instead?  So it just does it all in one go?

Comment: Yes I think so.  Line by line is memory efficient and you lose the line.Trim().

Answer (score 0):

This is what helped me in 2020, incase if someone is looking for this

```cs
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream))
{
   return Regex.Replace(sr.ReadToEnd().Trim(), @"\s", "");
}
```